# Merge map Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, mergemap

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

```js
this.scheduleService.GetZones(environment.systemId)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((zone: Zone) => {
      return this.dashboardService.GetLatestMeasurementValue(environment.systemId, zone.sensorId)
    })
    .subscribe(mois => {
      this.currentMoisture = mois;
    })
  );
}
```

I get this error:  Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot subscribe to an operator. You need to subscribe as follows.

```js
this.scheduleService.GetZones(environment.systemId)
    .pipe(
       mergeMap((zone: Zone) => {
          return this.dashboardService.GetLatestMeasurementValue(environment.systemId, zone.sensorId);
       })
     )
    .subscribe(mois => {
      this.currentMoisture = mois;
    })
```

Comment: `mergeMap` will keep your `this.scheduleService.GetZones` observable alive. if your services work the way i think they do, i'd consider `switchMap` instead, this will make sure `this.scheduleService.GetZones` will get unsubscribed.

Answer (score 0):

I see we are mapping zone value to the latest measure value by this method name `GetLatestMeasurementValue`.
If you are always interested in the latest value [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) is a better operator

```
this.scheduleService.GetZones(environment.systemId)
    .pipe(
       switchMap((zone: Zone) => {
          return this.dashboardService.GetLatestMeasurementValue(environment.systemId, zone.sensorId);
       })
     )
    .subscribe(mois => {
      this.currentMoisture = mois;
    })
```

And if it is a single time event simple `map` would also do the job as below :

```
this.scheduleService.GetZones(environment.systemId)
    .pipe(
       map((zone: Zone) => {
          return this.dashboardService.GetLatestMeasurementValue(environment.systemId, zone.sensorId);
       })
     )
    .subscribe(mois => {
      this.currentMoisture = mois;
    })
```